# K-medoids algorithm for time series with varying lengths

Tags: time-series, clustering, k-medoids

Can time series having multiple lengths be clustered using the k-medoids algorithm. I am essentially looking for a way to find a representative pattern from a set of time series using the k-medoids centroid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a big deal, but DTW is not a metric, it is only a measure.

Paper [a] does exactly what you want.

### However, if you have one long time series, as opposed to many short time series, they you should look at time series snippets [b].

[a] https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/ICDM_2014_DTW_average.pdf
[b] https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/Time_Series_Snippets_10pages.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt it via a suitable *distance*. Unlike k-means, k-medoid centers are chosen directly from data. So, you don't have to implement addition operation between data samples. It just remains to use a well-defined distance, i.e. $d(x_i,x_j)$. Several distances for time series with different lengths exist, e.g. [Dynamic Time Warping](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dynamic_time_warping). [This](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSdist/TSdist.pdf) library in `R` has many of them and also implements `K-medoids` algorithm with a lot of distance options.